# Uploader plus is not working for perticular site in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have multiple sites in Alfresco, uploader plus is working fine for other sites except one, throws an exception and error pop up says "operation failure".

uploader plus is working fine for the individual folders. but issue comes when we are applying this to the documentLibrary folder of a particular website.

Also not able to upload any document in that particular site, giving internal server 500 error.

Please refer attached screen shots for more details.

Let me know if you have any resolution/workaround for this issue.

Thanks in Advance.enter image description here [image]

**upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl File code :**

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
{
"status": ${status},
"node": {
"nodeRef": "${node.nodeRef}",
"path": "${node.displayPath}\/${node.properties.name}",
"allowedTypes": []
}
}
</#escape>
```

**Error :**

```
    2018-09-07 06:27:26,210  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-apr-8080-exec-21] Exception from executeScript: 08070089 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 08070869 Error during processing of the template 'get(properties) failed on instance of org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode. See cause exception.

The failing instruction:
==> ${node.properties.name} auto-escaped  [in template "com/piridn/uploader/upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl" at line 6, column 31]'. Please contact your system administrator.
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 08070089 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 08070869 Error during processing of the template 'get(properties) failed on instance of org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode. See cause exception.

The failing instruction:
==> ${node.properties.name} auto-escaped  [in template "com/piridn/uploader/upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl" at line 6, column 31]'. Please contact your system administrator.
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:519)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:587)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:656)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:428)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.module.aosmodule.service.ContextRootFilter.doFilter(ContextRootFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BaseSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor585.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebScriptSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor585.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebscriptCookieAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor585.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:132)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TemplateException: 08070869 Error during processing of the template 'get(properties) failed on instance of org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode. See cause exception.

The failing instruction:
==> ${node.properties.name} auto-escaped  [in template "com/xyz/uploader/upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl" at line 6, column 31]'. Please contact your system administrator.
    at org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:234)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.renderTemplate(AbstractWebScript.java:967)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(DeclarativeWebScript.java:267)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:147)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: get(properties) failed on instance of org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode. See cause exception.

The failing instruction:
==> ${node.properties.name} auto-escaped  [in template "com/piridn/uploader/upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl" at line 6, column 31]
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.get(BeanModel.java:222)
    at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:74)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.ListLiteral.getModelList(ListLiteral.java:126)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:115)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.EscapeBlock.accept(EscapeBlock.java:85)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:243)
    at org.alfresco.repo.template.FreeMarkerProcessor.process(FreeMarkerProcessor.java:230)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor633.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:912)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.invokeThroughDescriptor(BeanModel.java:275)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.get(BeanModel.java:182)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Object cannot be null.
    at com.hazelcast.impl.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:39)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl.check(MProxyImpl.java:473)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl.access$900(MProxyImpl.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl$MProxyReal.get(MProxyImpl.java:778)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl.get(MProxyImpl.java:114)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.cache.HazelcastSimpleCache.get(HazelcastSimpleCache.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.core.ClusteredObjectProxyFactory$AbstractClusteredObjectProxyInvoker.invoke(ClusteredObjectProxyFactory.java:293)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.cluster.core.ClusteredObjectProxyFactory$CacheProxyInvoker.invoke(ClusteredObjectProxyFactory.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.cache.TransactionalCache.getSharedCacheValue(TransactionalCache.java:454)
    at org.alfresco.repo.cache.TransactionalCache.get(TransactionalCache.java:641)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.TagScopePropertyMethodInterceptor.getTagSummary(TagScopePropertyMethodInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.tagging.TagScopePropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(TagScopePropertyMethodInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.MLPropertyInterceptor.invoke(MLPropertyInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.sync.SyncPropertyInterceptor.invoke(SyncPropertyInterceptor.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.invoke(NodeRefPropertyMethodInterceptor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor295.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor295.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.DisableAuditableBehaviourInterceptor.invoke(DisableAuditableBehaviourInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.authorization.AuthorizationStatusInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationStatusInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateNode.getProperties(TemplateNode.java:269)
    ... 99 more
2018-09-07 06:27:30,038  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@5ed2d0e7_Worker-3] Model tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 080721297 archive GetModelsDiff return status is 403
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:248)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:228)
    at org.alfresco.solr.component.EnsureModelsComponent.prepare(EnsureModelsComponent.java:87)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:292)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getResponse(Cloud.java:165)
    at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getSolrDocumentList(Cloud.java:149)
    at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.getDocsWithUncleanContent(SolrInformationServer.java:722)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ContentTracker.doTrack(ContentTracker.java:76)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:179)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Comment: Could you show us your application logs and check if there is no error in your browser's console ?

Comment: @Akah I have updated the server logs in the question body, please check and update

Comment: Please show us the file upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl, especially around the line 6.

Comment: @Akah, Updated upload-folders-new.post.json.ftl code in the question body

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the name of your file is null (which is not clear for me why).
This might be because the document your are uploading is not indexed yet.

Try to use the fileName of the file you uploaded instead of the name property of the node, or protect your line this way :

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
{
   "status": ${status},
   "node": {
     "nodeRef": "${node.nodeRef}",
     <#if node.properties.name??>
     "path": "${node.displayPath}\/${node.properties.name}",
     </#if>
     "allowedTypes": []
    }
}
</#escape>
```

Comment: I tried above solution, but still same issue is there. Also I am able to use uploader+ for other sites and folders, but its not working for the perticular site document library.

Comment: Please refer this link- https://github.com/softwareloop/uploader-plus/issues/122, my issue is similar like this, the mentioned that some node have a currupt name, but I didn't get any solution

Comment: Do the file or the directory have specific characters ?

Comment: its not working for particular site document library folder, and there is no any special character in the site name